# Is there path macros in IntelliJ IDEA that points to project directory ? (IDEA 10.5.2)

Tags: macros, path, intellij-idea

Is there path macros in IntelliJ IDEA that points to project directory ?

In build 10.5.2 that I have

```
${PROJECT_DIR}
```

is null.

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you use this variable? How did you verify that it's null?

Comment: I want to use it in additional command line parameter of GWT compiler. When I use `${PROJECT_DIR}` IDE throws an exception from the method StringUtils.replace() from utils.jar from IDEA folder. I decompiled it and saw that it happens only if value of macros is null.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some fields in IDEA run/debug configuration indeed accept `${PROJECT_DIR}` and `${MODULE_DIR}` variables, for example the working directory field, however it's not available in all the fields, like in your case when you want to pass a parameter to the GWT compiler.

There is already an [open issue related to your request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-74031), but you can file another one if you want.

Comment: Thanks. That's sad. Any ideas in what version in might be fixed ?

Comment: @CrazyCoder, when I record a macro, such as right click on a directory/module, it doesn't record that selection, so the activation of the macro happens on whatever happens to be active later on. Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41076187/intellij-recording-and-playing-macro-for-maven-generate-sources-and-update-f

Comment: @CrazyCoder Is there a way to record teh selection of a project before?